# Install Debian as system’s main OS from a bootable USB flash drive

Tags: linux, usb, debian, format

My system is running Windows 7 x64. I want to install Debian as the main OS from USB flash drive, and I have never did this before.

How can I make it to delete Windows 7 at all, and install Debian?

Do I need to have USB plugged all the time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Debian from a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/265723/how-to-install-debian-from-a-usb-drive)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bootable usb key. This is explained in this other post: [How to install Debian from a USB drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/265723/how-to-install-debian-from-a-usb-drive).

To answer the rest of your question:

- When you boot from the usb key, there is an option to install the OS on your computer. This will wipe out the current OS. You don't need to uninstall Windows 7 manually before.
- Once this is done, you don't need the usb key anymore, you can even reformat it to use it as a normal key again.

Don't worry, this is a pretty simple operation.

Comment: "there is an option to install the OS on your computer." http://prntscr.com/s9r4f1 this is the option ?